# Amazon EC2 instance goes offline

Tags: networking, amazon-ec2

I've set up a game server on Amazon EC2. However it is often going offline for ~10 minutes, failing a status check.

`Instance reachability check failed at January 31, 2016 at 8:10:00 PM UTC+1 (4 minutes ago)`

When it gets back online, it looks like it was just shut off from the internet. I can imagine it can be DDoS attacks from competing servers, but I am not sure how to come to a conclusion about that.

Does anyone have any clue what can cause this? Or how I can debug it?

Comment: What's the instance type of your instance?  Some of the smaller instances can be _very slow_ to respond (_e.g._ due to multi-tenancy hypervisor scheduling), and thus this might be one possible cause of "reachability" failure.

Answer (score -1):

I think you're running out of CPU credits on your burstable T-instance.

> When an instance starts to run low on CPU Credits, its performance
>   will gradually return to the baseline level (10% to 40% of a single
>   core, as listed in the table above). This deceleration process takes
>   place over the course of a 15 minute interval in order to provide a
>   smooth and pleasant experience for your users.

from here:
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/low-cost-burstable-ec2-instances/

Comment: Can you please quote the relevant information from the link?

Comment: This may be better as a comment.

Comment: @oldmud0, agree but I need more karma to leave comments.

Comment: @user630624 - If you understand it is a comment, and you understand comments should not be submitted as an answer, then you understand you shouldn't have submitted an answer better served as a comment.  So in the future don't do that, submit an answer, that matches the guidelines outlined in the help center.  The answer is fine, now that you have included the relevant information, but you should have done that before you submitted the answer.